# EF database concurrency

Tags: entity-framework, concurrency, dbcontext

I have two apps: one app is asp.net and another is a windows service running in background.

The windows service running in background is performing some tasks (read and update) on database while user can perform other operations on database through asp.net app. So I am worried about it as for example, in windows service I collect some record that satisfy a condition and then I iterate over them, something like:

```
IQueryable<EntityA> collection = context.EntitiesA.where(<condition>)
foreach (EntityA entity in collection)
{
  // do some stuff
}
```

so, if user modify a record that is used later in the loop iteration, what value for that record is EF taken into account? the original retrieved when performed:

```
context.EntitiesA.where(<condition>)
```

or the new one modified by the user and located in database?

As far as I know,  during iteration, EF is taken each record at demand, I mean, one by one, so when reading the next record for the next iteration, this record corresponds to that collected from :

```
context.EntitiesA.where(<condition>)
```

or that located in database (the one the user has just modified)?

Thanks!

Comment: EF uses lazy loading on enumeration. So when you call the foreach, collection is then going to be enumerated. This means that EF will make the DB call right at that moment. This means that if the enumeration has started, and the record is updated via the website then the record used within the foreach loop will be an old version or "the original retrieved" as you said.

Comment: @RollemIra what you describe is called 'deferred execution'. Lazy loading has to do with navigational properties that are loaded when they are accessed for the first time.

Comment: Good catch! Label it what you will, it won't be executed until enumeration.

Comment: @RollemIra so as I understand, then I am right: value is the old one and at each loop iteration, EF is polling database to read next record, right? If so now I am wondering if this does not affect performance because EF is polling database as many times as loop iterations... Maybe this would be another post about performance....As far as I know polling database constantly is not a good practise and it should be avoided if possible.

Comment: No, it does not pull each record individually, the whole collection is retrieved from the DB at the start of the foreach loop. See the first answer below, it should help a lot.

Comment: @RollemIra ok, I understand now, many thanks. And if the whole collection is retrieved from the DB at the start of the foreach loop, the whole collection is then placed in memory (RAM) right? Could it be a problem if there are a lot of records?

Comment: Yes this will be a problem if you have many records (but it will have to be a lot to run you out of ram on a modern machine). If you are finding that the resultset is too large a common solution is paging the results, eg `set.Where(something).OrderBy(something).Skip(1000).Take(1000)` will take the second page of 1000 rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a couple of process that will come into play here in terms of how this will work in EF.

1. Queries are only performed on enumeration (this is sometimes referred to as  query materialisation) at this point the whole query will be performed
2. Lazy loading only effects navigation properties in your above example. The result set of the where statement will be pulled down in one go.

So what does this mean in your case:

```
//nothing happens here you are just describing what will happen later to make the 
// query execute here do a .ToArray or similar, to prevent people adding to the sql 
// resulting from this use .AsEnumerable
IQueryable<EntityA> collection = context.EntitiesA.where(<condition>); 
//when it first hits this foreach a 
//SELECT {cols} FROM [YourTable] WHERE [YourCondition] will be performed
foreach (EntityA entity in collection)
{
    //data here will be from the point in time the foreach started (eg if you have updated during the enumeration in the database you will have out of date data)
    // do some stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're truly concerned that this can happen then get a list of id's up front and process them individually with a new `DbContext` for each (or say after each batch of 10). Something like:

```
IList<int> collection = context.EntitiesA.Where(...).Select(k => k.id).ToList();
foreach (int entityId in collection)
{
    using (Context context = new Context())
    {
        TEntity entity = context.EntitiesA.Find(entityId);
        // do some stuff
        context.Submit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer to your question is 'it depends'. The problem you are describing is called 'non repeatable reads' an can be prevented from happening by setting a proper transaction isolation level. But it comes with a cost in performance and potential deadlocks.

For more details you can read [this](http://databases.about.com/od/sqlserver/a/isolationmodels.htm)

Comment: I don't think this is the issue described here, non repeatable reads occur when atransaction is rolled back. This isntisn't what the op is describing. He is interested in what happens when the db changes. Do his entities immediaIly reflect the change it not